# Class attribute in <HTML> tag?

Tags: html

Is class a legal attribute of the HTML element?

```
<html class="...">
```

My Oracle ADF application does this — why?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It is not valid in [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.3):

```
<!ENTITY % html.content "HEAD, BODY">

<!ELEMENT HTML O O (%html.content;)    -- document root element -->
<!ATTLIST HTML
  %i18n;                               -- lang, dir --
  >
```

It is not valid in [XHTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#a_dtd_XHTML-1.0-Strict):

```
<!ELEMENT html (head, body)>
<!ATTLIST html
  %i18n;
  id          ID             #IMPLIED
  xmlns       %URI;          #FIXED 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'
  >
```

It is valid in [HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#global-attributes):

> The following attributes are common to and may be specified on all HTML elements (even those not defined in this specification):
>
> - ...
> - class
> - ...

---

> My Oracle ADF application does this - wounder why

Presumably to apply style or JS from a shared external file to specific pages.

Answer (score 8):

**There are some great reasons to use a class on the HTML tag.**

You can use such css globals to style around different pages, different browsers, etc.

[modernizr](http://modernizr.com) uses this technique

[css_browser_selector.js](https://raw.github.com/rafaelp/css_browser_selector/master/css_browser_selector.js) uses this technique

[Richard Pianka discusses](http://richardpianka.com/2011/01/css-browser-selector/) how the technique is used in the above css_browser_selector script

[Chris Coyier discusses](http://css-tricks.com/why-use-classes-or-ids-on-the-html-element/) why the technique is useful

Further Reading:

[Avoid setting a global class for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908447/avoid-setting-a-global-class-for-html)

Answer (score -2):

"The class attribute is not valid in: base, head, html, meta, param, script, style, and title".
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_class.asp

You can get what you want using this pattern :

```
<html>
   <body class="">
   </body>
</html>
```

or (better, I guess)

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Plz don't post w3school links. See [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) for the reasons.

Comment: It is also wrong (depending on which version of HTML is being used, w3schools fails to say which they are talking about).