# Avoid setting a global class for html

Tags: html, css, fuelux

I am trying to use [Fuel UX](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/). I copied its example to my own web page and found that the css could not be loaded. After comparing my HTML with the sample HTML, I find that the sample HTML sets a global class:

```
<html lang="en" class="fuelux">
```

Adding this line to the head of my HTML solves the problem with the Fuel UX. However adding this global setting mixes many other elements on my page. How can I set this `class="fuelux"` **locally**?

**EDIT:** As I understand `class="fuelux"` opens a namespace, and now all names under `.fuelux` is under the global namespace. Is there a way to avoid opening this `fuelux` namespace?

Thanks a lot!

Here is the html of a tree container in Fuel UX:

```
<div class="well tree-example">

  <div id="MyTree" class="tree">
    <div class="tree-folder" style="display:none;">
      <div class="tree-folder-header">
        <i class="icon-folder-close"></i>

        <div class="tree-folder-name"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tree-folder-content"></div>
      <div class="tree-loader" style="display:none">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tree-item tree-folder-content" style="display:none;">
      <i class="tree-dot"></i>

      <div class="tree-item-name"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: *How can I set this class="fuelux" locally?* means what?

Comment: As I said, if I remove `class="fuelux"`, my css cannot be loaded. So I need to set it somewhere, but not in the head of my page.

Comment: Your additional CSS files should work without `HTML` containing classes or not. I believe the Fuel UX CSS file is overwriting CSS properties from your additional CSS files. As you said, as soon as you remove the `fuelux` class from the `html` tag, Fuel UX doesnt apply any styles. Just make sure you use your stylesheets appropriately, also in the correct order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's the problem in using `<html class="fuelux">`? It is how the stylesheet is designed. I've picked up a snippet [from their stylesheet](http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/vendor/fuelux/css/fuelux.css). If you mark something here...

```
.fuelux .clearfix {
  *zoom: 1;
}

.fuelux .clearfix:before,
.fuelux .clearfix:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.fuelux .clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}

.fuelux .hide-text {
  font: 0/0 a;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
}

.fuelux .input-block-level {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 30px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fuelux article,
.fuelux aside,
.fuelux details,
.fuelux figcaption,
.fuelux figure,
.fuelux footer,
.fuelux header,
.fuelux hgroup,
.fuelux nav,
.fuelux section {
  display: block;
}

.fuelux audio,
.fuelux canvas,
.fuelux video {
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.fuelux audio:not([controls]) {
  display: none;
}
```

It selects the element which are nested under element having class of `fuelux` so you need to declare that on the `<html>` tag in order to get it work.

Also, `html` tag isn't considered as the head of the page. It is completely normal and accepted to declare a class on the `html` tag. It just selects the elements which are nested inside the `fuelux` class. If you still want to get rid of that class, than you can use it without declaring on any element, but you will have to tweak your stylesheet. You need to remove all the `.fuelux` classes before the other nested class in your CSS rules.

They are just using it so that it doesn't conflict with your other classes.

---

As per your comment, am throwing a demonstration here, suppose you are using `fuelux`, and in `fuelux` there's a class called `.button` and they are using color red for that class. So now, assume that the container `div` is your `html` element, it will select the inner nested element using this rule.

```
.fuelux .button {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EFfaC/)

Now lets assume that you removed the class from the `html` tag so see what happens ...

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/EFfaC/1/)

It won't apply the styles. Why? Because there's no nested element under `.fuelux` having a class of `.button`. Yes, you do have `.button` but it doesn't have any parent element with  class `.fuelux` so it fails.

Last but not the least, conflict demo. Assume that you have a class called `.button` already, and say even `fuelux` stylesheet has a class called `.button` and say you didn't used `class="fuelux"`, than it will simply ignore the `fuelux` rule and it will use yours.

[**Conflict Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/EFfaC/3/)

Comment: Suppose I have another css sytle file that has `.abc`. Obviously, the two namespaces have chances to conflict with each other if I introduce `fuelux` in the global namespace. (Sorry I am new to web dev, the terminology is from C++/Java.)

Comment: @JohnSket I explained with examples

Comment: Thanks! I got it. Instead of putting `<html lang="en" class="fuelux">`, I just introduce a new wrapper `div` around my fuelux part.

Comment: @JohnSket Yea, but be sure, outside the parent element, the styles won't apply :) and you welcome

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that you want the class `fuelux` to be stored somewhere and so then you will not need it to write it again and again then it's not possible.

One approach could be to create a simple script and then write a program to add `class=fuelx` to head of every page. It could be done more easily by putting your header in a seprate file and then including it and then run script on that page. More easy, now if your header is in a seprate file you don't need a script beacuse the header will be inluded in every file and then just write `class=fuelx` only once.

Or you can just remove `.fuelux` class from it's stylesheet than that way the stylesheet would not look for any `.fuelux` class and the style will be applied to all the elements that were first the sub-elements of the `.fuelux`.