# How to make the body, or even the HTML take the whole page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I'm basing the home page in the bootstrap Cover page. The images are placeholders. The site works fine in desktop, but when you resize to smaller sizes, the grid goes into single column, and the box-shadow does not follow the new size, it's as the body is set to 100vh, which is not.
[image]

As you can see, the shadow ends there, and doesn't come with the rest of the page.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
  
.big-box {
  max-width: 42em;
}
  
.nav-masthead .nav-link {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}
  
.nav-masthead .nav-link:hover,
.nav-masthead .nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}
  
.nav-masthead .nav-link + .nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}
  
.nav-masthead .active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.nav-masthead .active:hover {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

.row-space {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.grid-img {
    max-width: 80%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="h-100" lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-bg-dark">
    <div class="big-box d-flex w-100 h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
        <header class="mb-auto"> 
            <div>
                <h3 class="float-md-start mb-0">Bem Vindo</h3>
                <nav class="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center float-md-end">
                    <a href="index.html" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0 active">Home</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0">Cadastro</a>
                    <a href="" class="nav-link fw-bold py-1 px-0">Sobre</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
        <main class="px-3">
            <h1>Conheça aqui exemplos de fantasia fantásticos</h1>
            <p class="lead">Amoms</p>
            <div class="container">   
                <div class="row row-space">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle grid-img" src="poli.jpg" alt="Img 1">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle grid-img" src="poli.jpg" alt="Img 2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle grid-img" src="amumu.png" alt="Img 3">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row row-space">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle grid-img" src="poli.jpg" alt="Img 4">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle grid-img" src="poli.jpg" alt="Img 5">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="rounded-circle grid-img" src="amumu.png" alt="Img 6">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="mt-auto text-white-50">
            <p>Site feito para aula de desenvolvimento web por 
                <a class="text-white" href="https://github.com/Loknitro">@Leonardo Vecchi</a>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The row margin also disappear on mobile.

I've tried to remove the h-100 class from the html tag. That did resolve my problem, but created another one in the desktop, in which the height would not fill the whole screen.

Can anyone tell me what do i need to do, so that it works on both mobile and desktop?

Comment: I've edited your question so that your code is now a snippet that can be run directly from your question. For a snippet you don't need an entire HTML document, so now it doesn't have an `<html>` tag. However I would avoid putting css classes on the `<html>` tag anyway, that's something I've never really seen done before. I possible please update your code to include working image links because I don't really see your issue being reproduced right now

Comment: @ChrisBarr classes most definitely can go on the`<html>` tag. View the source of StackOverflow. In this case, the `h-100` could be considered bad practice (depending on what is trying to be accomplished), since it makes the height of the entire document 100% of the *browser window* and not taller. This may cause overflow issues.

Comment: @disinfor Yes I know they can go on the `<html>` tag, I only said it was not common and I did not recommend it.

Comment: @ChrisBarr it's quite common to put classes on the `<html>` tag. I think saying it's not recommended is more of an opinion vs. use case. There is a [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22620531/1172189) that specifically addresses reasons to use it. And the [w3.org spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#global-attributes) allows for it. Sorry to keep this comment thread alive, but it muddies the water a bit when comments suggest something isn't necessarily accurate.

Comment: @disinfor OK, fair enough.  I've re-edited the question to include this again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.

Removing the h-100 class from "html" and my main "big-box" div, and set the body min-height to 100vh worked well. I'll add the html and css changes here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body class="d-flex h-100 text-center text-bg-dark">
    <div class="big-box d-flex w-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
```

Style:

```
body {
  text-shadow: 0 .05rem .1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Now in the desktop it aligns perfectly and the background shadow follows the whole content while in mobile width.